# Wordpress Registration

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

My site uses (a customised) Login with Ajax plugin, which simply redirects users to the referring page upon signup/log in. Is there some way that I could hook into the registration javascript event and call Google Analytics manually to trigger the goal, or otherwise create a conversion event for when users register (but one that is not triggered by logging in)? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two options. Both would work by registering a "virtual URL" (and address that does actually exist in your website) for the confirmation page. You do this by adding the (virtual) page location to a pageview call:

```
ga('send','pageview','/thankyou.html');
```

One way is to edit your plugin code and add the above directly to the ajax success handler (the bit where the redirection happens after a successfull ajax response).

If for some reason you rather want to add tracking via  a global js file you can (at least if you are using jQuery, although undoubtedly other libraries have similar mechanisms), a [global ajax sucess handler](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) that hooks into all ajax events on your page and check if the called ajax url is that for your confirmation page:

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url == "ajax/thankyou.html" ) {
    ga('send','pageview','/thankyou.html');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful response! So to clarify, I would need to create a page called e.g., "Thank You" and then write this?
 ga('send','pageview','/thank-you');  But where would I write this code, exactly? How could I hook it into the Login with AJAX plugin?

Comment: If you use Ajax you are calling an url (not necessarily an html page) - that is was is referenced in the "settings.url"-Variable. The global event handler can go anywhere in the page, that's basically the advantage of it being global.

Comment: OK thanks for the clarification. I will look into implementing it! :)